# PHP Rotating image file after being decoded instead of rotating the image resource?

Tags: php

I'm getting my image from base64, decode it, then check if the image width is less than the height. If it is, rotate the image. However, `imagerotate()` only accepts resource.

```
imagerotate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

Here is the code:

```
$file_data = base64decode($input);
list($width, $height) = getimagesizefromstring($file_data);

        if($width < $height) {
            $file_data = imagerotate($file_data, 90, 0);
        }
```

How do I rotate the image without saving it first?

Comment: how about this? `imagerotate($input, 90, 0);`

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for this function? There's an example on the page showing exactly what input it is expecting. http://php.net/imagerotate

Answer (score 1):

I ended up properly creating the image resource, this works perfectly:

```
$file_data = base64decode($input);
list($width, $height) = getimagesizefromstring($file_data);

if($width < $height) {
    $file_rotate = imagecreatefromstring($file_data);
    $file_rotated = imagerotate($file_rotate, 90, 0);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($file_rotated);
    $file_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: You should also use `imagedestroy()` after outputting with `imagejpeg()`.